# How does RoamResearch design its backend for its linkable bulletpoints?

Tags: rest, database-design, architecture, graphql, backend

I have a hard time figuring out how they implement the feature exactly. I can imaging they have a Notes table and Ideas table. Each of the Ideas is one bullet point and kept with the order numbers, but I don't feel this is efficient. Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Do you have a link to an example of this linkable bullet points feature?

Comment: Yes. Can you check out [this video](https://youtu.be/5TuOwKpk0jA?t=197)? It is a feature that allow creating a backlink from a section of a note to another section in a different note.

Comment: To answer your question, they implement the linkable bullet points with code.  As far as a database, you'd have a Todo list.  Each Todo element is made up of to-do text, an optional Category link, and an optional cross-reference link to another note or an external document.

Comment: Interesting. I never thought about the Task and Subtask approach before. Thank you @GilbertLeBlanc <3